# C# - is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, xna

I can't figure out why this is the case. I'm creating a View class from Game class and then I'm trying to call a method from View in Game and send it the entire game object as a parameter. If I send single variables as a parameter then it work's no problem but I wanted to send the whole Game object so that only one thing would be passed.

Game class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Airfield
{
    public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        // Device Objects
        GraphicsDevice device = null;
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics = null;
        MouseState mouse;

        // Game Objects
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D b = null;
        View view = null;

        // Arrays
        Buoy [] buoy = new Buoy[3];
        Plane [] plane = new Plane[3];

        // Variables
        bool selected = false;
        int index = 0;

        public Game()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content"; 
            this.IsMouseVisible = true;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            base.Initialize();

            view = new View();

            for (index = 0; index < buoy.Length; index++)
            {
                buoy[index] = new Buoy();
                plane[index] = buoy[index].CreatePlane();
            }
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            device = graphics.GraphicsDevice;
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(device);
            b = Content.Load<Texture2D>("buoy");
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {

        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);

            mouse = Mouse.GetState();

            if (selected == true || mouse.X >= buoy[0].position.X - 3 && mouse.X <= buoy[0].position.X + 19 && mouse.Y >= buoy[0].position.Y - 3 && mouse.Y <= buoy[0].position.Y + 19)
            {
                if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    selected = true;
                    buoy[0].position= new Vector2(mouse.X - 8, mouse.Y - 8);
                }

                else
                {
                    selected = false;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Draw(gameTime);
            view.DrawScreen(this);
        }
    }
}
```

View Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Airfield
{
    class View
    {
        public View()
        {

        }

        public void DrawScreen(Game game)
        {
            game.device.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            game.spriteBatch.Begin();
            DrawBuoys(game);
            game.spriteBatch.End();
        }

        public void DrawBuoys(Game game)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < game.buoy.Length; x++)
            {
                game.buoy[x].DrawBuoy(game.spriteBatch, game.b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I get the error for every time that I try and use something that has come from Game.

Comment: Does passing it by reference help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that all of the members inside of `Game` are marked as `protected` or not marked at all which defaults to `private`.  This means that only `Game` and any classes which derive from it will have access to those `protected` members and no-one else to `private`.  The type `View` is a completely separate type and hence can't access any members that are `protected` or `private`.

To expose the `private` fields they need to be marked as `internal` or `public`.

```
public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
  ...
  public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
}
```

Most of these members are also labeled as `override` hence you are locked into `protected`.  But you can use another `non-protected` member to call into the `protected`.  It's not clear from the sample if you want to invoke these methods or not.

Answer (score 2):

All of this is implicitly `private`:

```
// Device Objects
GraphicsDevice device = null;
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics = null;
MouseState mouse;

// Game Objects
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Texture2D b = null;
View view = null;

// Arrays
Buoy [] buoy = new Buoy[3];
Plane [] plane = new Plane[3];

// Variables
bool selected = false;
int index = 0;
```

You'd need to change them to `public`, which is a bad idea for member variables. Or you can create properties to access the member variables:

```
public SpriteBatch SpriteBatch {
    get { return this.spriteBatch; }
    protected set { this.spriteBatch = value; }
}
```

Comment: It basically is telling you that these variables aren't public and you're trying to access them like they are.

Comment: If you're going to do that then consider eliding the backing field. `public SpriteBatch SpriteBatch { get; set; }` is shorter and easier; let the compiler make the backing field for you.

Answer (score 0):

By default in C# any fields that do not have accessibility explicitly defined are assumed to be private. So, you will need to do the following in your `Game` class:

```
    // Device Objects
    public GraphicsDevice device = null;
    public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics = null;
    public MouseState mouse;

    // etc... for your other fields
```

Second, it's worth noting that all of your `Game` class's methods have `protected` accessibility, which means that only classes that inherit from `Game` will be able to call those methods.